# PEM_read_X509 not reading entire certifcate

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, digital-certificate

I am using PEM_read_X509 API to read a certificate. The certificate file contains 2 set of certificate contents,

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
****<certificate content>****
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
*****<certificate content>****
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The issue is **PEM_read_X509** read only first cert and not reading the second certificate. I think the API will stop reading the certificate when it encounters **-----END CERTIFICATE-----**

Can anyone help on this...?

Comment: Based on your statement and the missing code, it sounds like everything is working as expected. You call `PEM_read_X509`, and you get a certificate back.

Comment: @jww PEM_read_X509 will read only the first certificate. Second part will not be read by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 X509* x;
 while(x = PEM_read_X509(file, NULL, NULL, NULL))
        X509_print_fp(stdout, x);
```